# Is there a way to see the number of successes and failures for each sendgrid webhook?

Tags: sendgrid

I am not seeing any view to see the status of my webhook calls - whether they are erroring or succeeding or how often they are called. Is there any view for that, or an API? Can I create an alert to alert me when a webhook fails to trigger?